# Dereferencing pointer to array of strings in Python ctypes

Tags: python-2.7, pointers, ctypes

I have this function for communicating with an optical laser tuner from its **C** library

```
long EXPORT newp_usb_get_model_serial_keys (char** ppBuffer);
```

where "ppbuffer" is "a pointer to an array of null terminated characters, where the array index is the 'DeviceID' and each element contains the Model/Serial Number key" (from the library header file). The function creates the array mention in ppbuffer's description and returns a 0 for success, non-zero for failure.

I've defined the following function in Python 2.7.15 as one of several to communicate with the laser:

```
from ctypes import *

def get_key(self):
    buf = create_string_buffer('\000'*1024)
    pbuf = pointer(buf)
    nread = c_ulong()
    status = self.lib.newp_usb_get_model_serial_keys(pbuf)
    if status != 0:
        raise CommandError("error")
    else:
        # dereference pointer and store/return values in the array
```

The newp_usb_get_model_serial_keys function is successful, but I've been having trouble dereferencing the pbuf pointer. I've struggled to understand some methods such as using cast() (and I'm not sure if that's what's best to use anyway), and using pbuf.contents simply returns

```
<ctypes.c_char_Array_1025 object at 0x0000000013557AC8>
```

which seems very different from what I've seen on other people's questions on similar topics.

I've tried using POINTER() instead of pointer() but there doesn't seem to be a ctype for a pointer to a string array for the first argument of POINTER(). I feel like there might be a better way to do this? Or maybe I'm just missing something here with how to access the strings being stored?

Comment: Does the function allocate and return a pointer to a buffer?

Comment: I don't think so, as far as I know the function uses the provided pointer to fill the corresponding array with the requested information from the remote laser device and then returns either success or failure. Though honestly I don't know all that much about C so I'm kinda learning as I go.

Comment: That can be done with just `char*` so step 1 is figuring out what the real function requirements are.  You can try `pbuf.contents.value` to see if anything is in the returned buffer, but it might not be the *same* buffer you passed if the function is returning a buffer.

Comment: Printing `pbuf.contents.value` just shows a blank line, so maybe it is possible that it's returning a separate buffer. The function definitely requires a pointer to the buffer, since it's documentation refers to the parameter `char** ppBuffer` as "a pointer to an array of null terminated characters," though I'm not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: I'm not sure my answer is exactly what you need.  If you could provide C code that calls the function successfully, or point to better function documentation, that would help.

Comment: I've been trying to find more information . The only documentation I have also says that "this function retrieves an array of device keys used to specify a particular device that is open on the USB bus. Each key is unique and consists of the Model and Serial Number strings concatenated together." The rest just says how if you use this function then you can refer to the device by its key. And I believe I was able to decompile the DLL that calls the function, but the C method is fairly long to put in a comment

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear how the function returns the value, but from the name it might be returning a pointer to an internal static buffer with serial/model information, so this should work.  Note I have set the `.argtypes` and `.restype` of the function for some type checking.

Test DLL:

```
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

long EXPORT newp_usb_get_model_serial_keys (char** ppBuffer)
{
    static char item[] = "hello, world!";
    *ppBuffer = item;
    return 1;
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('test')
dll.newp_usb_get_model_serial_keys.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char_p)]
dll.newp_usb_get_model_serial_keys.restype = c_long

p = c_char_p()
dll.newp_usb_get_model_serial_keys(byref(p))
print(p.value)
```

Output:

```
b'hello, world!'
```